# Is there a name for the "minimum" corner of a cube?

Tags: geometry

I'm wondering if there is either a colloquial or accepted standard name for the corner of an unrotated cube with minimal coordinate values across all axes? Is it the *bottom-left* corner, the *lowermost* corner, the *minimum* corner? It feels like there should be a name for this guy, but I can't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Usually you impose a coordinate system on the object, and place that point on the origin, so.

Comment: A mildly interesting question. I don't think any of those you posted are technically correct, since the first two only reference two directions (bottom-left could refer to two points, for instance) and the third seems like something that wouldn't generalize well (take the same cube and shift it to a different octant of the $xyz$ grid and the corresponding vertex is different). I'd just suggest labeling all of the vertices and to hell with whatever it could be called, now it's just a letter.

Comment: @DonThousand: this is a kind of non-answer. What if there are two cubes ?

Comment: When a point has all coordinates larger than those of another, you call it "dominant". So the vertex farthest from the origin would be the "most dominant" or just "dominant". But this concept is little known, and wouldn't be understood. I don't know the antonym.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer well the context of this question is to have a word that easily describes this corner in a sentence, no drawings allowed. I like least-dominant corner so far, but it indeed doesn't sound like something well known.